# PHP Amqp channel callback loop

Tags: php, php-amqplib

[The example code for RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) states

> Our code will block while our $channel has callbacks. Whenever we
>   receive a message our $callback function will be passed the received
>   message.

With this code snippet

```
while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

This confuses me, because [the default timeout for `PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel::wait` is forever](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php#L317).

`public function wait($allowed_methods = null, $non_blocking = false, $timeout = 0)`

So if `wait` blocks forever, how would the code ever reach a second iteration of the `while` loop?

Would it be safe to say the `while` loop is only necessary if `wait` is passed a `$timeout > 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout parameter on the `wait` call is how long to wait *for the next message* before giving up. The default value, as you say, is "forever", which means "until a message arrives".

However, once a single message has been received and processed, the `wait` call exits; it could perhaps be named `waitForNextEvent()`. You can see that in the source you linked to:

```
if ($this->should_dispatch_method($allowed_methods, $method_sig)) {
    return $this->dispatch($method_sig, $args, $amqpMessage);
}
```

So to receive more than one message, you need to call `wait()` more than once. Generally, in a consumer, you want to call it an infinite number of times, so you could just use `while(true)`, but allowing the loop to exit if you unregister all your callbacks gives you a way of gracefully exiting.

Answer (score 0):

the code you are showing, would represent the worker or processor of the AMQP messages

Because it will listen for dropped messages from the AMQP server, it will be waiting/listening/looping forever for these messages.

Comment: Right, but I believe `$channel->wait()` is already looping forever, so not sure what the point of the `while` loop shown here is when `$timeout=0` (the default for `wait`).